# Terraform module for GCP secret module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-secret-manager

Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on ..\Terraform_1.0.0_Win_O\config\secret\secret.tf line 6, in module "secret_user_managed_replication":
│    6:   replication {
│
│ Blocks of type "replication" are not expected here.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is not clear. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.